# How to avoid firebase functions recursion

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Following scenario:

Creating a quiz app. Whenever a user ends a quiz, his score is updated. On this update, the firebase function updates the ranking of all users:

```
exports.onMessageCreate = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {

    var test=  admin.firestore().collection('users');

    test.orderBy('totalScore', 'desc').get().then(querySnapshot => {
      var rank = 1;
      querySnapshot.forEach(user => {
        user.ref.set({globalRanking: rank}, {merge: true}).then(res => { });;
        rank++;
      });
    });

    return null;

  });
```

The problem is, that with `documentSnapshot.ref.set` the users are being updated again, so this triggers again every time the complete firebase function. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Would it be viable to compute the rankings with a firebase cloud function when a user requests it, instead of updating all rankings when data is changed?

Comment: That sounds like a valid answer @IanRehwinkel! :)

Answer (score 4):

Make it so when a user ends the quiz, he updates or pushes to a different node.
The function monitors that node and update all users ranking

Comment: I think @Ian Rehwinkel's answer is better

Comment: I don't think so, because that means you will recalculate the ranking everytime a user asks for it, where it might not have even changed, wasting processing cpu usage.

Comment: Afaik, firebase charges for the amount of requests to the database, not the cpu usage, so it wouldn't really matter too much. Unless you have several thousand users, the approach I proposed should be fine.

Comment: AFAIK, firebase charges for both.